# Javascript regEx: wrap words and spaces into tags

Tags: javascript, regex

I've been trying to achieve this: I want to wrap words into  tag and spaces (which may be multiple) in  tag, assuming original text can contain html tags that should not be toched

```
This is   <b>very bold</b> word.
```

convert to -->

```
<w>This</w><s> </s><w>is</w><s>   </s><b><w>very</w><s> </s><w>bold</w></b><s> </s><w>word</w>
```

What is the right regEx to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use two replacements >>

```
s.replace(/([^\s<>]+)(?:(?=\s)|$)/g, '<w>$1</w>').replace(/(\s+)/g, '<s>$1</s>')
```

Check [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/QPUz9/).

---

**EDIT**:

For more complex inputs (based on your comment below), go with >>

```
s.replace(/([^\s<>]+)(?![^<>]*>)(?:(?=[<\s])|$)/g, '<w>$1</w>').replace(/(\s+)(?![^<>]*>)/g, '<s>$1</s>');
```

Check [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/EfzW8/2/).

Comment: Can you explain the `(?=...)` part?

Comment: @SeanVaughn - Part `(?=\s)` means "followed by whitespace"

Comment: Great, but is it possible to modify your solution to handle "complex" tags for example <span style="font-weight:bold">very bold</span> instead of <b>very bold</b>?

Comment: Doesn't work for nested elements http://jsfiddle.net/EfzW8/1/ ("bold" not wrapped in <w>). You can add as many special cases as you want, I will always find a counterexample **by definition** http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky_hierarchy#The_hierarchy.

Comment: @Prinzhorn - First of all, OP asks for regex solution, so it is nice to find the closest regex solution. Your most recent example has `data-foo="<bar>"` tag parameter, which is possible, but very unlikely. As I don't know what kind of HTML source code OP needs to parse, it is hard to say how far with regex complexity we have to go. I believe my most recent code should work for OP.

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions are not suited for every task. If your string can contain arbitrary HTML, than it's not possible to handle all cases using regular expressions, because HTML is a context-free language and regular expressions covers only a subset of them. Now before messing around with loops and a load of code to handle this, let me suggest the following:

If you are in a browser environment or have access to a DOM library, you could put this string inside a temporary DOM element, then work on the text nodes and then read the string back.

Here's an example using a lib I wrote some month and updated now which is called [Linguigi](https://github.com/Prinzhorn/Linguigi)

```
var element = document.createElement('div');
element.innerHTML = 'This is   <b>very bold</b> word.';

var ling = new Linguigi(element);

ling.eachWord(true, function(text) {
    return '<w>' + text + '</w>';
});

ling.eachToken(/ +/g, true, function(text) {
    return '<s>' + text + '</s>';
});

alert(element.innerHTML);
```

Example: http://prinzhorn.github.com/Linguigi/ (hit the `Stackoverflow 12758422` button)